# Perl split a text file into chunks

Tags: perl

I have a large txt file made of thousand of articles and I am trying to split it into individual files - one for each of the articles that I'd like to save as article_1, article_2 etc.. Each articles begins by a line containing the word /DOCUMENTS/.
I am totally new to perl and any insight would be so great ! (even advice on good doc websites). Thanks a lot.
So far what I have tried look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $id = 0;
my $source = "2010_FTOL_GRbis.txt";
my $destination = "file$id.txt";

open IN, $source or die "can t read $source: $!\n";

while (<IN>)
  {
    {  
      open OUT, ">$destination" or die "can t write $destination: $!\n";
      if (/DOCUMENTS/)
       {
         close OUT ;
         $id++;
       }
    }
  }
close IN;
```

Comment: I've tried to re-indent what you pasted, properly, and I see a pair of redundant `{ }`s. Are you sure you've pasted the entire thing? Also, next time, please use the '{ }' button when pasting code in questions/answers.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that `/DOCUMENTS/` appears by itself on a line. Thus you can make that the *record* separator.

```
use English     qw<$RS>;
use File::Slurp qw<write_file>;
my $id     = 0;
my $source = "2010_FTOL_GRbis.txt";

{   local $RS = "\n/DOCUMENTS/\n";
    open my $in, $source or die "can t read $source: $!\n";
    while ( <$in> ) { 
        chomp; # removes the line "\n/DOCUMENTS/\n"
        write_file( 'file' . ( ++$id ) . '.txt', $_ );
    }
    # being scoped by the surrounding brackets (my "local block"),
    close $in;    # an explicit close is not necessary
}
```

**NOTES:**

- `use English` declares the global variable `$RS`. The "messy name" for it is `$/`. See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24RS)
- A line separator is the *default* ***record*** separator. That is, the standard unit of file reading is a *record*. Which is only, by *default*, a "line".
- As you will find in the linked documentation, $RS only takes literal strings. So, using the idea that the division between articles was `'/DOCUMENTS/'` all by itself on a line, I specified `newline + '/DOCUMENTS/' + newline`. If this is part of a path that occurs somewhere on the line, then that particular value will not work for the record separator.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Can you explain how works the record separator ? Should I declare the variable RS first ?

Comment: @user1562471, see Notes section, just added.

Comment: Thanks again. DOCUMENTS does not appear by itself on a line but is part of an expression such as "1 of 150 DOCUMENTS" so it will not work as a record separator. But I will try to find another separator that is a whole line.

Comment: That is great ! Thank you so much. I have found another separator and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Did you read [*Programming Perl*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004927)? It is the best book for beginning!

I don't understand what you are trying to do. I assume you have text that has articles and want to get all articles in separate files.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie qw(:all);

my $id          = 0;
my $source      = "2010_FTOL_GRbis.txt";
my $destination = "file$id.txt";

open my $IN, '<', $source;
#open first file
open my $OUT, '>', $destination;

while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;    # kill \n at the end
    if ($_ eq '/DOCUMENTS/') {  # not sure, am i right here or what you looking for
        close OUT;
        $id++;
        $destination = "file$id.txt";
        open my $OUT, '>', $destination;
    } else {
        print {$OUT} $_, "\n";     # print into file with $id name (as you open above)
    }
}
close $IN;
```

Comment: You can get rid of the first assignment to `my $destination`. Also I believe the OP meant that the string `/DOCUMENTS/` (as in a piece of a path in the file system) is a part of the header line for a new article, so you'd rather say `if (m{/DOCUMENTS/}) {`.

Comment: You re right "DOCUMENT" is part of the header of each article. But the above script does not work, the loops does not work I just get a file0.txt with all my articles inside.